# Error in Google App Engine "Could not change permissions on the launch config file"

Tags: google-app-engine

IN the Eclipse Data Source Explorer in database connection create a new connection for the Goolge Cloud Sql in it My Database Name is Guestbook & Instance Name is codeguestbook:appshilendra then in error window see the

**Could not change permissions on the launch config file**

in my jsp page my driver is **"jdbc:google:rdbms://codeguestbook:appshilendra/guestbook"** for google cloud sql connection driver when run the project

then I take the error **Could not change permissions on the launch config file** in the error window

Servlet Code is that @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException {

```
  PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
  Connection c = null;
    try {
      DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://codeguestbook:appshilendra/guestbook");
      String fname = req.getParameter("fname");
      String content = req.getParameter("content");
      if (fname == "" || content == "") {
        out.println("<html><head></head><body>You are missing either a message or a name! Try again! Redirecting in 3 seconds...</body></html>");
      } else {
      String statement ="INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) VALUES( ? , ? )";
      PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(statement);
      stmt.setString(1, fname);
      stmt.setString(2, content);
      int success = 2;
      success = stmt.executeUpdate();
      if(success == 1) {
        out.println("<html><head></head><body>Success! Redirecting in 3 seconds...</body></html>");
      } else if (success == 0) {
        out.println("<html><head></head><body>Failure! Please try again! Redirecting in 3 seconds...</body></html>");
      }
     }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          if (c != null) 
            try {
              c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
              }
      } resp.setHeader("Refresh","3; url=/guestbook.jsp");
  }
```

and the jsp code I'm using in it

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
  <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
  <%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Database Connection</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <%
   Connection c = null;
   c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://codeguestbook:appshilendra     /guestbook");
    ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT guestName, content, entryID   FROM entries"); %>
  <table style="border: 1px solid black">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <th width="35%" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Name</th>
   <th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Message</th>
     <th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">ID</th>
   </tr> <%
  while (rs.next()){
  String guestName = rs.getString("guestName");
   String content = rs.getString("content");
  int id = rs.getInt("entryID"); %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= guestName %></td>
  <td><%= content %></td>
   <td><%= id %></td>
  </tr>

 <% }
 c.close(); %>

 </tbody>
 </table>
 <br />


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could not change permissions on the driver file but why is possible

Comment: You should explain what you're doing, what's happening, and what you want to achieve, otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a stack trace with this error? You can open the "Error Log" view in Eclipse and possibly see one (if this error came from an exception, the full stack trace will be very important to helping debug the issue).

Thanks